# Correct Syntax for ui and nth-child call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm still a bit new on jquery selection syntax (and jquery in general). I'm not exactly sure how to get this call to work.

I'm using a function that gives me an event and ui. I'm using the [stop event in sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop) and I'm trying to get the nth-child (first) from this element and then trying to clear it's class. right now I have:

```
 stop : function(event, ui) {
     $(ui.item):nth-child(1).removeAttr("class");
 }
```

But this gives me an unexpected ':' error. What's the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) here, or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) (shortcut for `.eq(0)`), like this:

```
$(ui.item).eq(0).removeAttr("class");
//or:
$(ui.item).first().removeAttr("class");
```

The important difference to note here is that [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) (used as a string selector) is 1-based, [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (selector version) are 0-based.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works great! My question was not exactly what I needed, but I figure out that I had to combine it with a .find(). Thanks!